# OpenGL Shaders Not Drawing

Tags: c, opengl

I am currently using OpenGL 4.5, and reading the OpenGL Superbible Seventh Edition. Now, I am not using the projects they supplied, but I am instead, rolling my own project. However, based on what I understand thus far, it should be putting something on my screen, but I am getting nothing.

I have 3 total files. `Source.c`, `Loader.h`, and `Loader.c`

Code for Source.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <GL\wglew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include "Loader.h"

#define CL_BUFFER (GLfloat[4]) { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f }

int main(void);
void err(int error, const char * msg);
void keypress(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);

int main(void) {
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;


    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Fididdler", NULL, NULL);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
    if (window == NULL)
        return -1;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(err);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keypress);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        return -1;

    printf("GL Version String: %s \n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    GLuint RProg = LoadAllShaders();

    printf("Loading complete");
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, CL_BUFFER);
        glUseProgram(RProg);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); 
        /* End drawing logic*/

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
}

void err(int error, const char * msg) {
    printf("Error: %s", msg);
}

void keypress(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    }
}
```

The Loader header:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>


#pragma once

extern GLuint LoadAllShaders();
extern void LogCompileStatus(GLuint Shader, char* ShaderName);
```

The Loader C file

```
#include "Loader.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static const GLchar* VSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n",
    "void main(void)\n",
    "{\n",
    // Right here is what I am expecting to be drawn, but it is not
    "   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),",
    "                                    vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),",
    "                                    vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));\n",
    "   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];\n",
    "}\n"
};

static const GLchar* FSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n",
    "out vec4 color;\n",
    "void main(void)\n",
    "{\n",
    "   color = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);\n",
    "}\n"
};

GLuint LoadAllShaders() {
    GLuint VShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(VShader, 1, VSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(VShader);
    LogCompileStatus(VShader, "VShader");

    GLuint FShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(FShader, 1, FSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FShader);
    LogCompileStatus(FShader, "FShader");


    GLuint Program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(Program, VShader);
    glAttachShader(Program, FShader);
    glLinkProgram(Program);

    glDeleteShader(VShader);
    glDeleteShader(FShader);

    return Program;
}

void LogCompileStatus(GLuint Shader, char* ShaderName) {
    // Checking compile status of VShader
    if (ShaderName == NULL || sizeof(ShaderName) == 0)
        ShaderName = ("Unnamed Shader with ID: %i" + (char)&Shader);
    GLuint ShaderSuccess = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv(Shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &ShaderSuccess);

    if (ShaderSuccess == GL_TRUE)
        printf("Shader %s successfully compiled\n", ShaderName);
    else {
        GLint LogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(Shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &LogLength);

        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(LogLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(Shader, LogLength, NULL, buffer);

        printf("%s failed to compile.\n%s\n", ShaderName, buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, I am doing everything that's "necessary" from the tutorial, but I am not getting the same results. This is the output I get.

[image: VS + OpenGL + Console]

Comment: Seems like you haven't actually specified anything to draw. You need to create a VBO, fill it, and bind it before drawing.

Comment: But isn't that why you have the vec4 array in the shader? (for the sake of the tutorial). I added a comment for what I am expecting to be drawn.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. The shader is called **vertex shader** because it is called per **vertex**. However, since you don't actually specify any vertices, your program won't do anything. OpenGL works by sending some buffered data down the graphics pipeline, applying transformations along the way. Since the various shaders are just transformation steps in this pipeline, you cant specify your data completely in it.

Comment: @BenSteffan `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);` draws 3 vertices. And each one has no attributes. But that doesn't matter because the vertex shader pulls the position out of thin air.

Comment: @BenSteffan
Your suggestion was indeed correct. But, the way I declared my shader source was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 0 idea why the manner in which I declared the VSource was incorrect, but re-referencing the source in the textbook showed that having commas at the end of the quotation marks (for the GLSL source) was what broke it.

Code was

```
/// EOL commas broke this
static const GLchar* VSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n",
    "void main(void)\n",
    "{\n",
    "   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),",
    "                                    vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),",
    "                                    vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));\n",
    "   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];\n",
    "}\n"
};

static const GLchar* FSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   color = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n"
};
```

Code should be

```
static const GLchar* VSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n",
    "void main(void)\n",
    "{\n",
    "   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),\n",
    "                                    vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),\n",
    "                                    vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));\n",
    "   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];\n",
    "}\n"
};

static const GLchar* FSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n"
};
```

Edit:

I just figured out why it wasn't working. The "Shader Code" to human-eyes was correct, but it was only reading the first line of the vertex shader, which was an empty shader program. The GLSL compiler reads 1 entry, instead of all of them.